# URLs not opening in native app

Tags: default-applications

Samsung Galaxy S7, stock Android 7.0

I have the Meetup app installed.

If I go to App settings → Meetup → Set as default → App links:

- Go to supported URLs is set to "Via this app".
- Supported web addresses lists `meet.meetup.com` among others.

In Gmail, I click a link that starts with `https://meet.meetup.com/wf/...`, and... it opens in Firefox, not in the Meetup app.

How do I get it to open in the correct app?  It's super frustrating that my settings are being ignored.

Then, after it loads in Firefox, I have an Android icon in the address bar, indicating that it can open in a native app:

[image: Android icon that indicates the URL can be opened in a native app]

I click that icon and... it opens a new tab in Firefox.

I tried the [Open Link in App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.snarfed.android.openinapp&hl=en) app, and the link... still opens in Firefox, without asking me which app I prefer.

I tried the [Open Link With...](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tasomaniac.openwith&hl=en) app, and allowed Usage Tracking.  I *Share link* and send it to that app, and it gives me the option of whether to open in Meetup or Firefox.  I select "Meetup / Always", it says

[image: Opening link with Meetup]

and then... opens in Firefox.

[image: Jackie Chan WTF??]

Comment: @beeshyams If I open Meetup app settings → Set as default, and change "Go to supported URLs" to "Ask always" it still opens in Firefox.

Comment: Wondering if it is app specific issue or settings not working universally. Latter can be verified by say forcing Maps app to open in a browser when you click a link (by selecting *Don't open in this app*. If Maps (or any other app) respect your choice, issue is with this particular app else settings have gone wrong and I don't know how it can be fixed. Last resort is to use an [app like this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.betteropenwith) . You will fund this app recommended on this site for like situations

Comment: Could it be that the Meetup app can't handle the link so is silently redirecting you to Firefox? If you open the Meetup app directly, does it say anything worrying, such as that you're not logged in?

Comment: @DanHulme The Meetup app itself works fine and I'm logged in, but maybe you're right and it can't handle that specific URL even though it is registered to handle the domain.  I'll experiment with other apps later.

Comment: @DanHulme You might be right.  I installed *Better Open With*, and it pops up asking me if I want to open in Meetup or a selection of browsers, I select Meetup, and then it immediately pops up a second time asking me which of the browsers to open with, with no Meetup option, as if Meetup app is trying to open the browser.

Comment: @DanHulme Though now that I try again, clicking the same `https://meet.meetup.com/...` link, among others, the *Better Open With* just suggests 3 web browsers. 

Comment: But Goodreads links work from Gmail to that app, and Yelp links from Gmail open in that app.  ... But then I click the exact same Yelp link and it only offers me web browsers.  ... Wait, now I switched Meetup back to "Via this app" and links started opening in the app!!!  This makes no sense.  It varies from one click to the next.

Comment: And `https://dsp.stackexchange.com/...` links don't open in the app, despite `*.stackexchange.com` being in the "supported web addresses" list. ... Google Photos does work, though.